# Caching queries in Jooq

Tags: java, database, jooq

I try to use jooq in a project, but for performance reasons I want to cache queries. At the user manual in [performance consideration section](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-execution/performance-considerations/), query caching is mentioned but there are no examples about how it can be achieved. So i try to cache a query (for example SimpleSelectConditionStep) as following:

```
SimpleSelectConditionStep query = getFromPool();
if(query != null) {
    factory.attach(query);
    query.bind(1,"John");
} else {
   // create query
   factory.select(PERSON).where(PERSON.NAME.equal("Michael"));
}
// fetch and use query
result = query.fetchOne();
.....
putToPool(query);
```

My software is a multi threaded web application but it is guaranteed than two different threads can not use same query at the same time (pool not return same query before it put to the pool again).

I know than factory is not a thread safe object but I wonder that using query like this in the code can cause problems?

Comment: Are you sure you need to cache queries? Even if it's mentioned in the manual, this should only be needed when queries are executed very often, in case of which you might even want to cache the `PreparedStatement`, or at least the SQL String...

Comment: One of the pages in the application has quick response as requirement. I measure the time taking by operations and the longest are preparing statement are fetching the data. I try to cache sql string but after re executing sql string, i can only get a generic result instead of a generated record.

Comment: Is your example a real-life one? Or is your query really much bigger? I doubt that you'd need a cache for such simple cases. Do you have any profiling data, showing the hot spots of query execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If preparing the statement takes a long time, you might be able to use jOOQ's statement reusing feature:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/reusing-statements

This will internally keep an open statement within the query, if the same query is executed very often. Other than that, I doubt that for a simple query as in your example, you should need a cache for the jOOQ object.